# Replace Add to Cart button on WooCommerce single product page if cart is not empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I have the following PHP code in my Code Snippets App (plugin):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'message_when_other_product_already_in_cart', 10 );
function message_when_other_product_already_in_cart() {
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > 0) {
    $message = 'Before you can add another product to your cart, please complete your         purchase or empty your cart.';
       echo '<b><p><p>'.$message.'</b></p>';
}
}
```

What I require is a way to Hide the Add to Cart button as well. Not sure what I can use in the PHP code to just hide the button. In a question I asked sometime ago, It was recommended I use:

```
if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > 0) {
        $is_purchasable = false;
}  
    return $is_purchasable;
```

But due to our requirements having changed, I only want to **hide the button** as well as display the message "Before you can add . . ." I do not want to use $is_purchasable = false; Is this possible?

I tried various approaches, including a way to embed CSS in the PHP code. However, all efforts failed to simply hide the Add to Cart button.

Answer (score 1):

The following will replace add to cart button with a custom text message, on single product pages, if the cart is not empty:

```php
// Add to cart replacement text message
function add_to_cart_replacement(){
    // Your message text 
    $message_text = __( "Before you can add another product to your cart, please complete your purchase or empty your cart.", "woocommerce" );
    
    // Display the text message
    echo '<p class="button message">' . $message_text . '</p>';
}
// Replacing the single product add to cart button by a custom text message
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_single_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function replace_single_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;
    
    // If cart is not empty
    if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ){
        // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'add_to_cart_replacement', 20 );
        }
        // For all other product types
        else {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_to_cart_replacement', 30 );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, LoicTheAztec. I appreciate the response. However, it doesn't work for me. Not sure why. Perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned Single Product Page, but rather for it to be applicable to all products, regardless of page location, and with the condition if the cart is not empty or greater than 0.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, it's due to your theme customization on WooCommerce, or a third party plugin that affect WooCommerce, or some custom code that you are using, making changes to WooCommerce. In this case, I can't really help, as I can't guess by magic what is making trouble... But My code works on Most themes, as I use WooCommerce dedicated hooks, made for that.